# Superimposing two plots in R with same axis and limits

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two plots from two different data frames

The DPUT from data frame 1 is as follows

```
ppv_npv2 <- structure(list(pred.prob = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 
44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 
44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 
44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("ppv_2.5", "ppv_50", "ppv_97.5"), class = "factor"), 
value = c(4.8, 9.3, 13.4, 17.2, 20.8, 24.2, 27.3, 30.3, 33.1, 
35.7, 38.2, 40.5, 42.8, 44.9, 46.9, 48.8, 50.6, 52.3, 54, 
55.6, 57.1, 58.5, 59.9, 61.2, 62.5, 63.7, 64.9, 66, 67.1, 
68.2, 69.2, 70.2, 71.1, 72, 72.9, 73.8, 74.6, 75.4, 76.2, 
76.9, 77.7, 78.4, 79, 79.7, 80.4, 81, 81.6, 82.2, 82.8, 83.3, 
7.2, 13.6, 19.3, 24.4, 28.9, 33, 36.8, 40.2, 43.3, 46.2, 
48.9, 51.3, 53.6, 55.7, 57.7, 59.6, 61.3, 62.9, 64.5, 65.9, 
67.3, 68.6, 69.8, 70.9, 72, 73.1, 74.1, 75, 75.9, 76.8, 77.6, 
78.4, 79.2, 79.9, 80.6, 81.3, 82, 82.6, 83.2, 83.8, 84.3, 
84.8, 85.4, 85.9, 86.3, 86.8, 87.3, 87.7, 88.1, 88.5, 11.7, 
21.1, 28.8, 35.3, 40.8, 45.5, 49.7, 53.3, 56.4, 59.3, 61.8, 
64.1, 66.2, 68.1, 69.8, 71.4, 72.9, 74.2, 75.5, 76.6, 77.7, 
78.7, 79.7, 80.5, 81.4, 82.2, 82.9, 83.6, 84.3, 84.9, 85.5, 
86, 86.6, 87.1, 87.6, 88.1, 88.5, 88.9, 89.3, 89.7, 90.1, 
90.5, 90.8, 91.1, 91.5, 91.8, 92.1, 92.4, 92.6, 92.9)), 
.Names   =c("pred.prob","variable", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -150L), 
class    = "data.frame")
```

The plot that i have created is from the following code

```
p1 <- ggplot(ppv_npv2,aes(x=pred.prob,y=value))+
geom_line(data=ppv_npv2[ppv_npv2$variable=="ppv_50",],
colour="red",linetype=2)+
geom_line(data=ppv_npv2[ ppv_npv2$variable=="ppv_2.5", ],
colour="blue",linetype=4)+
geom_line(data=ppv_npv2[ ppv_npv2$variable=="ppv_97.5", ],
colour="blue",linetype=4)+
theme_classic()+
ylab("Predicted positive predictive value (%) \n")+
xlab("\n Prevalence (%)")+
scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,50),breaks=seq(0,50,2))+
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,100),breaks=seq(0,100,10), expand=c(0,0))+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=12,hjust=.5,vjust=.8,face="plain"),
axis.text.y = element_text(size=12,hjust=.5,vjust=.8,face="plain"))+
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=14,face="bold"),
axis.title.y = element_text(size=14,face="bold"))

p1
```

The dput for the second data frame is

```
dat <- structure(list(PPV = c(57, 89, 19, 52, 52, 62, 63, 46, 31, 52, 
54, 13, 17, 47, 48, 52, 96, 88, 64, 33, 62, 77, 75, 72), Prevalence = c(19, 
35, 12, 16, 24, 6, 28, 13, 8, 19, 30, 6, 8, 20, 11, 25, 29, 55, 
46, 13, 16, 22, 23, 20), total = c(939L, 323L, 306L, 703L, 137L, 
833L, 360L, 317L, 440L, 2072L, 209L, 386L, 142L, 358L, 167L, 
503L, 180L, 233L, 342L, 478L, 4870L, 1104L, 1813L, 1567L), 
Author = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
15L,18L, 19L, 8L, 14L, 16L, 17L, 21L, 20L, 20L, 13L, 10L), 
.Label = c("Aldous", 
"Bahrmann", "Body", "Christ ", "Collinson", "Eggers", "Freund", 
"Giannitis", "Hammerer-Lercher", "Hoeller", "Inoue", "Invernizi", 
"Keller", "Khan", "Lotze", "Melki ", "Normann", "Santalol", "Sebbane", 
"Shah", "Thelin "), class = "factor"), Study.assay = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("TnI", "TnT"), class = "factor")),
.Names = c("PPV", "Prevalence", "total", "Author", "Study.assay"), 
class ="data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

And the plot from dataframe 2 is as follows

```
p2 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=dat$Prevalence, y=dat$PPV, size=dat$total,  
label=dat$Author),guide=F)+
geom_point(colour="white", fill="red", shape=21)+
scale_size_area(max_size = 10)+
scale_x_continuous(name="\n Prevalence", limits=c(0,100))+
scale_y_continuous(name="Predicted positive predictive value (%) \n",   
limits=c(0,100))+
geom_text(size=2.5)+
theme_classic()+
ylab("Predicted positive predictive value (%) \n")+
xlab("\n Prevalence (%)")+
scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,50),breaks=seq(0,50,2))+
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,100),breaks=seq(0,100,10), expand=c(0,0))+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=12,hjust=.5,vjust=.8,face="plain"),
axis.text.y = element_text(size=12,hjust=.5,vjust=.8,face="plain"))+
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=14,face="bold"),
axis.title.y =   element_text(size=14,face="bold"))+
theme(legend.position='none')
p2
```

As you can see both plots have the same axis and limits. I have two questions:

a) Can i overlay plot 2 onto plot 1?

b) Can i make the bubbles on plot 2 more transparent and choose colours by the factor dat$Study.assay (green and purple)?

Many thanks in advance - have spent a day researching this but no solution yet.

Comment: It would be better if you reduced this to a minimum example rather than all this data and all this details on the plots.

Comment: The solution is to practice using ggplot2 properly; it is meant to produce plots where variables are "mapped" to aesthetics. In your second question "Can i make the bubbles on plot 2 more transparent and choose colours by the factor dat$Study.assay", the solution is to use `aes(color=Study.assay)` *without* the `dat$` before it. You should remove any trace of `dat$` in your `ggplot()` call. By declaring that `data=dat`, it will take care of the variable interpretation for you. Once you do that, the solution to the main question is to combine the two data frames and plot them all at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a start using your data,

```
(plot2 <- ggplot() + 
     geom_line(data = ppv_npv2,aes(pred.prob, value, 
               group= variable, colour = variable)) +
     geom_point(data = dat, aes(Prevalence, PPV, label=Author, size = total, 
               colour = Study.assay), alpha = I(0.4)) +
     geom_text(data = dat, aes(Prevalence, PPV, label=Author, 
               size = total), size=3, hjust=-1, vjust=0) 
)
```

[image: jshjh]

It's not the *orthodox* ggplot2 way, but it's a start.

Comment: No need for `aes()` when you’re specifying `NULL` data anyway. Indeed, no need for `NULL`, either: `ggplot() + …` works just fine.

Comment: Hello Eric / Konrad - this works excellent. Thank you so much. Can I be a pest and ask three few aesthetic questions a) how do i change the colours and line type for the first geom_line command so that the middle line appears red (solid) and top and bottom lines appear blue (dashed), b) how can i change the color of the bubbles to green and purple and finally c) is it possible to jitter the text so that they don't overlap. Thank you so much again!!

Comment: Glad it's helpful. If you could describe what you have tried, where you have searched for information, and exactly where you are stuck it's easier for us to help you. Aside from that I can only point to what @Matt74 wrote above "[t]he solution is to practice using ggplot2 properly." I know this might not be the answer you are looking for, but if you want other people to do your work–or their expertise–you should find a consultant who can help you.

Comment: Hello Eric - wasn't intending for other people to do my work for me at all. I have just got stuck and usually the solutions are very nicely provided in this board when one does come across an obstacle. In fact your earlier solution was exactly that. I have tried to input the scale_color_manual and linetype within the geom_line function  as follows geom_line(data = ppv_npv2,aes(pred.prob, value, group= variable, scale_colour_manual = c("blue","red","blue", linetype=c("dashed","solid","dashed")) but R does not seem to like it. Was just searching for a neat solution as your code did the trick.